# Mt_rand returns 0

Tags: php, random

```
mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Run a couple of times gives me the following output:

```
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
0
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
0
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
-3445259641993297920
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
0
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
0
php > echo mt_rand(~PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX) . PHP_EOL;
0
```

It does not seem very random. Could anyone explain why it so often returns 0? I was expecting a "random" number between the lowest and highst available

Even more, if you change it abit like

`echo mt_rand(-PHP_INT_MAX, PHP_INT_MAX)`

It will start returning 1 instead of 0

Comment: just give a limit in integer format like 5 ,10 and try?

Comment: Then it works as expected. I am not looking to get a random number, but to understand the lack of anything near random with this specific input

Comment: Getting several zeros in a row is *totally* random.

Comment: try mt_rand(-mt_getrandmax(), mt_getrandmax()); :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php. mt's max may not necessarily be PHP's int max...

Comment: @jay: relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's the problem with random numbers. [You can never really know if they're random](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: Absolutely relative @MarcB

Comment: I love that I received two relevant cartoons for my comment here @Machavity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to read the manual when in doubt.

[PHP - mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

> *Caution* The distribution of mt_rand() return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32.
>   This is because if max is greater than the value returned by
>   mt_getrandmax(), the output of the random number generator must be
>   scaled up.

As mentioned in the comments by [marcio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438563/marcio) the right solution would be

`mt_rand(-mt_getrandmax(), mt_getrandmax())`